# How to replace the actionbar by a popup menu?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-popupwindow, android-actionmode

I want to achieve 1 of these options for my EditText :

- Replace the actionbar that appear on the top by a **popup menu** instead. Something like this for exemple:

[image]

- Or make the actionbar floating and child of my current view (in some way same a first option)

i need this because i add my view via windowManager.addView(view, Layout_Params); and in this way i have some trouble with the actionbar on the top (it is displayed blank)

actually i do this to show the actionbar :

```
@Override
public ActionMode startActionMode(ActionMode.Callback callback) {
    Activity host = (Activity) this.getContext();    
    return host.getWindow().getDecorView().startActionMode(callback); 
}
```

but it's don't work, it's show me an empty white actionbar on the stop instead :( i think i need to create myself the ActionMode but i don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. You can hide the actionbar when your edittext is gained focus. Then you need to show the popup menu where ever you want.

```
EditText t = new EditText(this);
    t.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
            if(b){
                getSupportActionBar().hide();
                //now show your popup menu at the top position
            }else{
                getSupportActionBar().show();
                //here you dismiss the menu.
            }

        }
    });
```